# Toolbar set as ActionBar not displaying Title with setSupportActionBar

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I have the following problem.

I am trying to add a Toolbar, as an `ActionBar`, but the Toolbar is not showing the application name by default. Is there something wrong in the way I am setting up my `ActionBar`?

Here is my Layout xml file for the toolbar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbarMain"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Here is my main activity, which includes the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.andrewkp.gaassessing.Assessments">

    <include layout="@layout/main_toolbar"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And finally, where I set the `setSupportActionBar`.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_assessments);

        //get the toolbar instance
        Toolbar tb = findViewById(R.id.toolbarMain);
        setSupportActionBar(tb);
    }
```

I think the problem is something to do with the following:
In my `onCreate()` method of Activity java class, the type of Toolbar is '`android.support.v7.widget`', where the Toolbar placed in the layout is `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`?  Is there not a type mismatch here?

Comment: what was your toolbar `android:theme="@style/AppTheme` theme? use this one `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);` to show title after set the actionbar

Comment: Cast your Toolbar class

Comment: @Shailesh Setting that works, but this was not necessary the other day when I tried to create my first demo app.  Also, when I set the Overflow menu on the Toolbar, it does not show??

Comment: May be your theme is different. Check it and set as per your requirement

Comment: Check my updated answer.  What theme should I use?

Answer (score 0):

You can set title programmatically.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_assessments);

    //get the toolbar instance
    Toolbar tb = findViewById(R.id.toolbarMain);
    setSupportActionBar(tb);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Your app title");
}
```

Comment: You have to override onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) and inflate menu.xml in the method.

Answer (score 0):

Your code work perfectly fine for me. May be show title property is set to false for you. Try this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //get the toolbar instance
    Toolbar tb = findViewById(R.id.toolbarMain);
    setSupportActionBar(tb);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
}
```

Hope this solves your no title issue...